# How many transactions go on-chain if a user unilaterally exits from an Ark?

Tags: taproot, ark

In [Ark](https://www.arkpill.me/), if Alice decides to unilaterally exit will this means the entire tree must be revealed? How is congestion control handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single user to unilaterally exit, they only have to broadcast their vtxo tree *branch*. This means your personal vtxo leaf tx and all the transactions that are between the leaf and the on-chain Ark tx. For a tree of `n` vtxo leaves, this generally means `log2(n)` transactions.

[image]

Comment: For a better understanding of this diagram, see this answer: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/119835/96732