# What does this diagram mean?

Tags: ark

On this [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/119790/how-many-transactions-go-on-chain-if-a-user-unilaterally-exits-from-an-ark) Steven Roose used the following diagram:

[image]

What this exactly means?

Here is my take:

1. In a shared UTXO of 4 participants (A, B, C and D), each will receive a redeem transaction that they can broadcast anytime to receive their sats back;
2. But this redeem Tx is not a single Tx but instead a chain of Tx;
3. So each participant will receive 2 chained Tx they can broadcast anytime;
4. This means the number of Tx on this redeem transactions will be log2(n) where n is the total number of participants (imagining 8 participants, the redeem Tx would be made of 3 chained Tx)

Is this correct?

Comment: This question is already answered here https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/119834/how-does-the-unilateral-exit-process-in-ark-work